# Possible compiler error while generating generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing a method with the following signature:

```
public class Map<TSource,TDestination>
{
    public void Map<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>(
            Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceProperty>> sourcePropertySelector,
            Expression<Func<TDestination, TDestinationProperty>> destinationPropertySelector,
            Expression<Func<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>> converter ){}

}
```

The method gets called like this:

```
example1- Map( a => a.StringProperty, b => b.IntProperty, c => Int32.Parse( c ) )
example2- Map( a => a.NullabelInt32, b => b.Int32, c => c == null ? 0 : c)
```

When calling that method it happens that TDestinationProperty is not always of the right type, that is the exact type of the property being selected.

In the above example1 `TDestinationProperty` is correctly of type `Int32`; but in example2 `TDestinationProperty` always ends up being the same as `TSourceProperty`, that is, in example2 specific case, `Nullable<int>`.

Since i rely on that type to perform other complex operations, all the following fails. 
I though it had something to do with recompilation of the solution so i clean up and recompile but that bit just don't work.

To be honest i still have a working workaround for this but the point is to understand if i'm facing some kind of compilation bug or something.

Any idea? Can you reproduce that?

Comment: Would this work: `... c => c == null ? 0 : c.Value)` ?

Comment: You can do `c => c ?? 0`.

Comment: Side note: please re-read [MCVE] guidance... Your really don't need such complicated type to show the behavior - one parameter would be enough `Map(Func<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>> converter)... and `c => c == null ? 0 : c` can be simplified to `c => c`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `?:` operator, it will return a type that is compatible to both `0` and `c` which is `Nullable<int>` because `c` is a `Nullable<int>`. And because if `Func<TDestination, TDestinationProperty>` had `TDestinationProperty` be `Nullable<int>` the `b.Int32` would still be a legal return type due to auto promotion of types it uses the 3rd paramter to determine the type.

If you change your 2nd line to

```
Map( a => a.NullabelInt32, b => b.Int32, c => c == null ? 0 : c.Value)
```

it should work fine.

Comment: A little satisfaction i like to share: I'm really happy to say that something sparkled in my mind while getting asleep tonight and i finally figured this out by myself. Very uplifting to wake up and see my question answered and my thoughts confirmed. Thank you very much for the concise explanation.

Answer (score 3):

So, let's see what the compiler can infer about the expression `Expression<Func<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>> converter` when passed a lambda of `c => c == null ? 0 : c`.  We know that `c` is a `Nullable<int>` from the resolution of the first parameter, so `TSourceProperty` is `Nullable<int>`, you don't seem to have any issue with that.  So what is the value of this expression?  The expression calls the conditional operator; the first operand is of type `int` and the second operation is of type `Nullable<int>`, since that's what `c` is.  So what should the type of the whole conditional operator be?  Well, since `int` is implicitly convertible to `Nullable<int>` and `Nullable<int>` is *not* implicitly convertible to `int`, the type of the whole conditional operator is `Nullable<int>`, which makes that the type of the return value of the lambda, which makes it the type of `TDestinationProperty`.

If you want `TDestinationProperty` to be an `int`, then you'll need to convert `c` into an `int` in that lambda.  You could write: `c => c == null ? 0 : c.Value`, but the whole thing can just be shortened to `c => c.GetValueOrDefault()`.

Comment: This is also a correct answer, i just prefer @ScottChamberlain one because is more concise. Thank you!